# (While using a cube map) box-like textures appearing around my scene whenever I move the camera

Tags: opengl, camera, cubemap

I've been learning about cube map and I implemented one into my program. It seemed to work well until I started moving the camera around the scene and zooming out. As you can see in the attached gif, there seems to be a problem with the cube map since this weird behavior is occurring:

https://gyazo.com/70ad4ce027d1e032bc19258e28def66f

Main program:

```
        unsigned int cubemapTexture = texo.loadCubeMap(faces);

        glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);
        bg.bind();
        skyBox.use();

        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)scr_width / (float)scr_height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        skyBox.setUniformMat4("projection", projection);
        skyBox.setUniformMat4("view", view);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE20);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTexture);
        GLCall(glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36));
```

loadCubeMap:

```
unsigned int Textures::loadCubeMap(std::vector<std::string> faces)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(false);

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char* data = stbi_load(faces[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
        if (data)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
                0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data
            );

            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Cubemap tex failed to load at path: " << faces[i] << std::endl;
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


    return textureID;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec3 TexCoords; 

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoords = aPos;
    //Setting z value to w (1.0) so that the cube map is always in the background
    gl_Position = pos.xyww;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 TexCoords;
uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(skybox, TexCoords);
}
```

The problem probably originates from one of these snippets, but if you have any other ideas I can provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL) - your skybox is z-fighting against itself; changing the depth func to GL_LEQUAL will fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a really stupid mistake from my part.